# ruby on rails simplework calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, calendar, partial

good day,

i am  rendering simple work calendar work days only and i wish indicate  active day

source is on  https://gist.github.com/netmoleCBA/c9fd3029a997fb50798774ec7200d080 but very shortly

controller

```
require 'date'
class HomeTouchController < ApplicationController
layout 'touch'
def index
    session[:actualday]=Date.today()
    @week=session[:actualday].at_beginning_of_week..session[:actualday].at_end_of_week).first(5)
    @day=session[:actualday]
  end
end
```

index template

```
<%= @week.each do |actualday| %>
<%= render partial: 'den', locals: { actualday: actualday, day: @day }%>
<%end%>
```

partial template den.html.erb

```
<%=if @actualday.wday=@day.wday%>
 <li><a  hreflang="cs-cz" class="menu-item active" ><i class="mdi mdi-numeric-5-box right-3"></i><%= l activeday%></a></li>
<%else%>
 <li><a  hreflang="cs-cz" class="menu-item" ><i class="mdi mdi-numeric-5-box right-3"></i><%= l activeday%></a></li>
<%end%>
```

thanks for any advices

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code:

## controller

```
require 'date'
class HomeTouchController < ApplicationController
layout 'touch'
def index
    session[:actualday] = Date.today()
    @week =(session[:actualday].at_beginning_of_week..session[:actualday].at_end_of_week).first(5) #MISSING (
    @day = session[:actualday]
  end
end
```

## index.html.erb

```
<% @week.each do |actualday| %>
    <% if actualday.wday == @day.wday %>
      <li><a hreflang="cs-cz" class="menu-item active"><i class="mdi mdi-numeric-5-box right-3"></i><%= l activeday%></a></li>
    <% else %>
       <li><a hreflang="cs-cz" class="menu-item"><i class="mdi mdi-numeric-5-box right-3"></i><%= l activeday%></a></li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: undefined method `wday' for nil:NilClass  in first line  of partial ? any ideas

Comment: btw i dont know why i see whole hash in view  http://picpaste.com/pics/pole-eULQkMbX.1498719135.png